# What god if any do Asgardians worship in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, religion

After watching *Vikings* on the History Channel, Floki and the other characters are always talking about the gods Odin and Thor. This got me thinking, in the Marvel Cinematic Universe what god, if any, does Thor worship ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that those that pose as gods are unlikely to have a personal faith.

Comment: Actually, in the comics, there are references to "Those Who Sit Above In Shadow". They are quite mysterious.

Comment: @Richard - tell that to JC. </blasphemy off>

Comment: In comparison with Living Tribunal Asgardians are rather insignificant.

Answer (score 6):

Thor is a god in Norse mythology. Therefore, he doesn't believe in a religion. *He is the religion himself.*

In Norse mythology that is mentioned in Vikings is so different than MCU references of Nordic items. However, they share the same origins.

In Marvel Comics (Earth-616) there are references to the Norns. Norns are the fate incarnate. Even the Aesir and the Vanir respect and fear them. There wasn't any mention in MCU about them so far.

Short story, Asgardian Gods do not have other gods to believe. They are the ones who are worshipped.

Comment: In Norse mythology the tree Yggdrasil and fate (represented by the Norns) seem to be beyond  the Asgardian Gods, though not in a worship sense.  In particular the Asgardians are unable to avoid the devastating and foreseeable consequences of Ragnarok, though in the MCU film *Thor: Ragnarok* the outcome is very different for Thor - more evidence of a departure from the original mythology.

Answer (score 5):

There is no evidence of any specific religious believes held by Thor in the MCU. This doesn't mean he doesn't have them or that they could never be introduced, but the MCU varies from Norse myth and faith on a number of points, while drawing from others. Explicitly outlining Thor's faith (if any) is likely made considerably more complicated as a result.

That said, the MCU has been vague about the religous beliefs of most of the characters (with the notable exeception of Steve Rogers, who avers his faith publicly in Avengers). The writers may simply not be interested in answering the question in general.